# NightmareJS cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js

В javascript не силен, был парсер на curl php. Но больше он уже для Яндекс Маркета не подходит. Начал смотреть в сторону phantomjs и nightmarejs. С фантомом справился но тоже через 2-3 запроса капча, при условии что запросы это обновление страниц в промежутке 5-10 минут. Поставил NightMarejs все отлично, но не как не могу передать куки, они очень нужны для выбора региона. https://yadi.sk/i/MxBkUqYu3L4Dkb

Код вот такой

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/pars', function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain; utf-8'});
// Prepare output in JSON format
response = {
   link:req.query.link
};
console.log(response);

var Nightmare = require('nightmare'),
//nightmare = Nightmare();
nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });



nightmare.goto(req.query.link, {encoding: 'utf8'})
.cookies.set('yandexmarket', '24%2CRUR%2C1%2C%2C%2C%2C2%2C0%2C0%2C2%2C0%2C0')
.evaluate(function(){
 return document.querySelector('html')
  .innerHTML;
})

//.end()
.then(function(title){
res.end(title);
})

 //res.end(req.query.link);
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

var host = server.address().address
var port = server.address().port

console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

Как я только не пытался их передать, он просто не реагирует, причем в фантоме очень легко они передаются и работают. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Нашел вроде описание проблемы github.com/segmentio/nightmare/issues/921 что вроде как они не успевают погрузится куки. Но все решения не смог внедрить в свой код.

Comment: Есть одно костыльное решение. Сначала делаю goto(market.yandex.ru), потом .cookies.set, а потом еще раз goto уже на нужную страницу. Все работает, но это очень много занимает время, для парсинга не подходит так как открытие лишней страницы идет.

Comment: Если полноценный браузер использовать?